# javascript mouseover image swap issues

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I am trying to swap out a hover image with javascript but it doesn't seem to be working, any idea why? I thought this was the correct way to do this.

```
<li>
   <a onMouseOver="document.fbi.src=images/facebookIconHover.jpg" onMouseOut="document.fbi.src=images/facebookIcon.jpg"
href="http://www.facebook.com">
     <img src="images/facebookIcon.jpg" NAME="fbi">
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: No, not with inline code! Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Yes, that is the way of doing it, last century.

Comment: i would be open to better suggestions with jquery also

Comment: Fun fact: You don't need to use JQuery to handle a small mouse over event. Cripe, it's like using a moped instead of walking 3 feet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all you need to do (assuming those images exists) is put single quotes around the `src` string.

```
onMouseOver="document.fbi.src='images/facebookIconHover.jpg'"
onMouseOut="document.fbi.src='images/facebookIcon.jpg'"
```

I would suggest you use CSS `:hover` for the images though, as it separates presentation from content/scripting.

```
#element {
   background-image:url('url1.png');
}
#element:hover {
   background-image:url('url2.png');
}
```

Comment: I thought we were told to never touch the DOM directly and instead to abstract DOM manipulations via jQuery to avoid browser weirdnesses.

Comment: @frenchie I'm just trying to answer the OP's concern. We're also told to not mix website logic with presentation, but JQuery sure screws that up. The web's littered with bad practices.

Answer (score 0):

Via jQuery:

```
$('img[name="fbi"]').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','images/facebookIconHover.jpg');
},function(){
    $(this).attr('src','images/facebookIcon.jpg');
});
```